# .NET BroadcastWindow Error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here is the problem

- I have an .NET WinForm application which uses a third party DLL(which makes calls to a COM object.)
- When the application starts the third party dll functions opens a **LogWindow**(which I am fine with)
- When I call Application.Exit() on certain machines I keep getting ".NET BroadcastWindow Error" and it opens a dialog window. But my application closes normally and I can see that this error occurs after my window is closed.
- The error message also says that there was an error accessing memory location at "xx" location.

Here are some things that I have tried

- Put Application.Exit() in a try catch block - I don't get an Exception there. The error seems to occur after this step
- Get all active forms in the application and disposing them explicitly.

None of these seem to work.

Is this something to do with the **LogWindow** trying to communicate with my form after it has been closed?

Does anyone know about any programmatic fix for this?

Thanks!

Links found after a bit of googling. These doesen't seem to help for now

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/fb267827-1765-4bd9-ae2f-0abbd5a2ae22
- http:// social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5f39516f-111b-4462-b3b5-0cbb46be7ba4

Comment: Get friendly with the 3rd party.  Buy them beer, girls, a vacation in Bermuda.

Comment: @Hans Hah! We had a hard time setting up the whole environment - contacting those guys was a nightmare!

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem only the 3rd party can solve unless you have the source code.

If you want to really track down the error you can try http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Also how are you communicating with this 3rd party DLL.

Can you close it down before you close your application. Try setting everything related to it, to null if there is no shutdown method.

Then call Application.Exit()

Otherwise as Hans suggested, get friendly with the 3rd party.

Comment: - I did try the reflector. Reached nowhere ; As far as I checked they haven't provided any functions which I could call to close their window; This application is IVR related and uses drivers. I am going to contact them to get the latest drivers and then try again.  Thanks for your help!